# ¿Cómo puedo buscar en la última línea de múltiples archivos?

Tags: shell-script, awk

Estoy tratando de buscar en varios logs una cadena de texto, hacer que valide con una condición y me imprima el nombre del archivo y un texto:

```
ls -ltrh | awk '{
    if ($0 ~ /successfully completed/) {print FILENAME,FECHACREACIÓN,"COMPLETADO_CORRECTAMENTE"}
    else {print FILENAME,FECHACREACIÓN,"ERROR"}
    };' *.log
```

La idea es que valide en la última línea si existe una cadena "successfully completed" y si existe me muestre COMPLETADO CORRECTAMENTE, y si no me muestre error.

Pero actualmente sí existe la cadena y me arroja error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me gusta la respuesta de Patricio Moracho.

Para complementarla, sugiero que utilices una serie de procesos:

```
for f in *.log; 
do
     tail -n1 "$f" | grep -q "successfully completed" && echo "$f --> COMPLETADO CORRECTAMENTE" || echo "$f --> ERROR"
done
```

Básicamente, esto recorre todos los ficheros `*.log` de modo automático (en lugar de [parsear la salida de `ls`, que puede ser peligroso](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)) y extrae la última línea. A ella les hace un `grep` silencioso que si encuentra el texto "successfully completed" devuelve acierto y lanza el `echo "completado correctamente"` y si no el de "error".

Comment: Funciona correctamente y mas eficiente que lo que tenia anteriormente, pero quisiera saber si se puede agregar otro condicional, es decir que valida con "successfully completed" con "completed with" y si no existe ninguna de las dos ahi si imprimir error

Comment: Adicional a esto se podria imprimir en lugar de  "-->" la fecha de creación del archivo *.log?

Comment: @JesúsHenríquez eso son nuevos requerimientos que necesitarían de una edición en la pregunta, o bien una pregunta nueva.

Comment: listo, ya la edite

Comment: Porcierto el ENDFILE no me funciona :S

Comment: @JesúsHenríquez tal y como comenté en la respuesta de Patricio, ENDFILE solo está disponible en GNU Awk

Comment: Vale mejor hago otra entrada para este inconveniente ya que es diferente el problema

Answer (score 3):

Por empezar el `ls -ltrh` no te da un formato razonable para procesar luego con `awk` y el otro problema es que estarías imprimiendo un mensaje por cada línea leída.

Una forma sería combinando `bash` y `awk`:

```
for i in *.log; do awk 'END{if ($0 ~ /successfully completed/){print FILENAME,"-->","COMPLETADO_CORRECTAMENTE"} else {print FILENAME, "-->","ERROR"}}' $i;done
```

Por el lado del Script `awk`

```
END{
       if ($0 ~ /successfully completed/){
          print FILENAME,"-->","COMPLETADO_CORRECTAMENTE"
       }  else {
          print FILENAME, "-->","ERROR"
       }
}
```

Mucho más compacta aún es la sugerencia de @fedorqui de usar la regla [`ENDIFLE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html), disponible en GNU Awk, con lo cual evitamos tener que preprocesar en `bash` los archivos:

```
awk 'ENDFILE{if ($0 ~ /successfully completed/){print FILENAME,"-->","COMPLETADO_CORRECTAMENTE"} else {print FILENAME, "-->","ERROR"}}' *.log
```

Usamos la regla `END` para ejecutar justo cuando hayamos leído el archivo completo, verificamos si justamente la última línea tiene el texto buscado. Lo que no es óptimo es que `awk` leea completamente el archivo aunque solo necesitemos la última fila. Tal vez una solución usando `tail` sea mejor.

En el caso de `ENDFIILE`, entra en este bloque cada vez que termina de procesar un fichero.

Comment: Buena respuesta. De hecho, con GNU Awk el bucle `for` no es necesario: puedes usar `awk '...' *.log` y ya. Entonces, en lugar de decir `END` puedes utilizar [`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html). En cuanto a lo óptimo, tienes razón. Existe una herramienta llamada `tac` que imprime el fichero de abajo a arriba; en tal caso, podría utilizarse como fuente de Awk y luego hacer un `exit` tras procesar la primera línea.

Comment: @fedorqui, no conocía el `ENDFILE` y no había pode generar una solución leyendo múltiples archivos desde `awk`, voy a probarlo!

Comment: La solución que me indicas funcina pero solo me muestra el ultimo archivo, por eso quisiera hacerlo con ls -ltrh para que me analise todos los archivos. Y he tratado de implementarlo con tail pero no me gunciona

Comment: Raro lo que dices @JesúsHenríquez, no se me ocurre que puedes ser, lo he probado en un Linux y en Windows/Cygwin y muestra cada uno de los archivos.

Comment: Cree un archivo awk con la instruccion que me dices y lo llamo desde una sheel de esta forma: for i in *.log;
    do 
        awk -f test.awk $i;
    done

Comment: Pero lo anterior no me esta imprimiendo nada en pantalla

Comment: Es decir al parecer funciona todo, pero no valida correctamente que la cadena este en la ultima linea y por lo tanto no imprime, cambie el else por else if, y deberia imprimir completado correctamente por que dentro de los logs esta la cadena :S

Comment: El ENDFILE no funciona correctamente

Comment: Es raro que no te imprima nada, si no logra encontrar la cadena al menos debería imprimirte el error. Revisa esto 
https://asciinema.org/a/sdsloP9DgDk4HkJOHBW5eQakt por si encuentras alguna pista.